# Split large directory into subdirectories

Tags: language-agnostic

I have a directory with about 2.5 million files and is over 70 GB.

I want to split this into subdirectories, each with 1000 files in them.

Here's the command I've tried using:

```
i=0; for f in *; do d=dir_$(printf %03d $((i/1000+1))); mkdir -p $d; mv "$f" $d; let i++; done
```

That command works for me on a small scale, but I can leave it running for hours on this directory and it doesn't seem to do anything.

I'm open for doing this in any way via command line:  perl, python, etc.  Just whatever way would be the fastest to get this done...

Comment: Your `*` is going to take a while to expand. Maybe start with a more targeted filename subset like `a*` and see if that returns in a more reasonable amount of time. You might also look at using 'find' instead of the for-loop. Also I'd be concerned about creating subdirectories within this already-too-large directory. Have you considered creating them elsewhere?

Comment: I would recommend processing the results of `find`.

Comment: Only very well-written shells can handle strings resulting from commands or wildcard expansion that are in the multi-MB size range. Reading the directory in a program is fast and easy (see @ikegami). - If you want to use a shell script: subdivide the problem by piping `ls` into `while read ... done` to get the files one by one.

Comment: @laune: Letting `*` expand to 2.5 million filenames in a `for` loop is _not_ the problem _per se_  - in fact, `for f in *; do ...` is quite a bit _faster_ than `ls | while read ...`.
The problem is 2.5 million invocations of multiple external utilities.

Comment: @mklement0 You don't want a single mv for each file. A factor of 1000 cuts this down to a manageable size. -- But with a maximum command length of 2.088.198 (according to xargs --show-limits), I don't think that an expansion of * for 2.5 million is going to work. -- All of this only goes to show that this task is a bit too much for shell scripting. Perl is good enough, and we all know it'd be a cinch with C (or even Java).

Comment: @laune: Indeed, and that's why neither `for  f in *` nor `ls | while read` are a solution. The maximum command-line length does _not_ come into play, because the results of the expansion of `*` are not passed to an _external utility_ (not that the limit doesn't apply to _builtins_ such as `printf` either, which my answer relies on). And, agreed, a shell script is not the right solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect that if you checked, you'd noticed your program was actually moving the files, albeit really slowly. Launching a program is rather expensive (at least compared to making a system call), and you do so three or four times per file! As such, the following should be much faster:

```
perl -e'
   my $base_dir_qfn = ".";
   my $i = 0;
   my $dir;
   opendir(my $dh, $base_dir_qfn)
      or die("Can'\''t open dir \"$base_dir_qfn\": $!\n");

   while (defined( my $fn = readdir($dh) )) {
      next if $fn =~ /^(?:\.\.?|dir_\d+)\z/;

      my $qfn = "$base_dir_qfn/$fn";

      if ($i % 1000 == 0) {
         $dir_qfn = sprintf("%s/dir_%03d", $base_dir_qfn, int($i/1000)+1);
         mkdir($dir_qfn)
            or die("Can'\''t make directory \"$dir_qfn\": $!\n");
      }

      rename($qfn, "$dir_qfn/$fn")
         or do {
            warn("Can'\''t move \"$qfn\" into \"$dir_qfn\": $!\n");
            next;
         };

      ++$i;
   }
'
```

Comment: The problem is 2.5 million iterations of _invoking multiple external utilities_, not building up an internal array of all filenames up front, via `*`.
An _empty_ loop over 2.5 million files takes only about 25 seconds on my laptop running Ubuntu 14.04: `time for f in *; do :; done`
Adding just _one_ simple external utility to the mix - e.g., `time for f in *; do date; done >/dev/null` - increases execution time dramatically; I killed the command after about 30 minutes.
Your Perl solution is so much faster, because everything is done in-process.

Answer (score 3):

Note: **[ikegami's helpful Perl-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36511395/45375) is the way to go** - it performs the entire operation in a *single* process and is therefore much faster than the Bash + standard utilities solution below.

---

A `bash`-based solution needs to avoid *loops in which external utilities are called* order to perform reasonably.
**Your own solution calls *two external utilities* and creates a *subshell* in each loop iteration, which means that you'll end up creating about 7.5 million processes(!)** in total.

The following solution avoids loops, but, given the sheer number of input files, will still take quite a while to complete (you'll end up creating 4 processes for every 1000 input files, i.e., ca. 10,000 processes in total):

```
printf '%s\0' * | xargs -0 -n 1000 bash -O nullglob -c '
  dirs=( dir_*/ )
  dir=dir_$(printf %04s $(( 1 + ${#dirs[@]} )))
  mkdir "$dir"; mv "$@" "$dir"' -
```

- `printf '%s\0' *` prints a NUL-separated list of all files in the dir.

  - Note that since `printf` is a Bash *builtin* rather than an external utility, the max. command-line length as reported by `getconf ARG_MAX` does *not* apply.
- `xargs -0 -n 1000` invokes the specified command with chunks of 1000 input filenames.

  - Note that `xargs -0` is nonstandard, but supported on both Linux and BSD/OSX.
  - Using NUL-separated input robustly passes filenames without fear of inadvertently splitting them into multiple parts, and even works with filenames with embedded *newlines* (though such filenames are very rare).
- `bash -O nullglob -c` executes the specified command string with option `nullglob` turned on, which means that a globbing pattern that matches nothing will expand to the empty string.

  - The command string counts the output directories created so far, so as to determine the name of the next output dir with the next higher index, creates the next output dir, and moves the current batch of (up to) 1000 files there.

Comment: You can afford a loop over the directories (but not the files).

Comment: @laune: Yes, but there's no simple way to _robustly_ pass batches of 1000 filenames to a `while` loop directly from `xargs`  (your approach doesn't work with filenames with embedded spaces and/or filenames that happen to be valid globs).
By letting `xargs` pass each batch of 1000 filenames as individual arguments (without shell involvement) to `bash`, they are correctly preserved.

Answer (score 2):

if the directory is not under use, I suggest the following

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | split -l 1000 -d -a 5
```

this will create n number of files named x00000 - x02500 (just to make sure 5 digits although 4 will work too).  You can then move the 1000 files listed in each file to a corresponding directory.

perhaps `set -o noclobber` to eliminate risk of overrides in case of name clash.

to move the files, it's easier to use brace expansion to iterate over file names

```
for c in x{00000..02500}; 
do d="d$c"; 
   mkdir $d; 
   cat $c | xargs -I f mv f $d; 
done
```

Comment: ++, but (a) with _GNU_ `find` the resulting list of filenames will not be sorted, unlike with glob `*`, (b) assuming that the OP's `xargs` supports `-0`, using `tr '\n' '\0' < "$c" | xargs -0 -J f mv f "$d"` will be much faster; (c) as I've done in the snippets in (b), I suggest double-quoting the variable references to promote good habits, even though it's not strictly necessary here.

Comment: yes files won't be sorted but I'm not sure it's a requirement.

Comment: It's not stated as a requirement, but given that the OP based his own approach on `*`, the difference is worth mentioning. I just realized that `-J` is a _BSD_ `xargs` option; with GNU utilities the more efficient command must therefore be stated as `tr '\n' '\0' < "$c" | xargs -0 mv -t "$d"`; and just to be explicit: your `-I f` approach moves each file _individually_.

Comment: In a somewhat ironic twist, the only place where you currently do use double quotes is where they are _never_ needed (though they don't hurt): `d="d$c"` never needs double quotes, irrespective of the value of `$c`.

Answer (score 0):

Moving files around is always a challenge. IMHO all the solutions presented so far have some risk of destroying your files.  This may be because the challenge sounds simple, but there is a lot to consider and to test when implementing it.

We must also not underestimate the efficiency of the solution as we are potentially handling a (very) large number of files.

Here is script carefully & intensively tested with own files. But of course use at your own risk!

This solution:

- is safe with filenames that contain spaces.
- does not use *xargs -L* because this will easily result in "Argument list too long" errors
- is based on Bash 4 and does not depend on *awk*, *sed*, *tr* etc.
- is scaling well with the amount of files to move.

Here is the code:

```bash
if [[ "${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}" -lt 4 ]]; then
  echo "$(basename "$0") requires Bash 4+"
  exit -1
fi >&2

opt_dir=${1:-.}
opt_max=1000

readarray files <<< "$(find "$opt_dir" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f)"
moved=0 dirnum=0 dirname=''

for ((i=0; i < ${#files[@]}; ++i))
do
  if [[ $((i % opt_max)) == 0 ]]; then
    ((dirnum++))
    dirname="$opt_dir/$(printf "%02d" $dirnum)"
  fi
  # chops the LF printed by "find"
  file=${files[$i]::-1}
  if [[ -n $file ]]; then
    [[ -d $dirname ]] || mkdir -v "$dirname" || exit
    mv "$file" "$dirname" || exit
    ((moved++))
  fi
done

echo "moved $moved file(s)"
```

For example, save this as *split_directory.sh*. Now let's assume you have 2001 files in *some/dir*:

```bash
 $ split_directory.sh some/dir
mkdir: created directory some/dir/01
mkdir: created directory some/dir/02
mkdir: created directory some/dir/03
moved 2001 file(s)
```

Now the new reality looks like this:

- *some/dir* contains 3 directories and 0 files
- *some/dir/01* contains 1000 files
- *some/dir/02* contains 1000 files
- *some/dir/03* contains 1 file

Calling the script again on the same directory is safe and returns almost immediately:

```bash
 $ split_directory.sh some/dir
moved 0 file(s)
```

Finally, let's take a look at the special case where we call the script on one of the generated directories:

```bash
 $ time split_directory.sh some/dir/01
mkdir: created directory 'some/dir/01/01'
moved 1000 file(s)

real    0m19.265s
user    0m4.462s
sys     0m11.184s
 $ time split_directory.sh some/dir/01
moved 0 file(s)

real    0m0.140s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.123s
```

Note that this test ran on a fairly slow, veteran computer.

Good luck :-)

Answer (score -1):

This is probably slower than a Perl program (1 minute for 10.000 files) but it should work with any POSIX compliant shell.

```
#! /bin/sh
nd=0
nf=0
/bin/ls | \
while read file;
do
  case $(expr $nf % 10) in
  0)
    nd=$(/usr/bin/expr $nd + 1)
    dir=$(printf "dir_%04d" $nd)
    mkdir $dir
    ;;
  esac
  mv "$file" "$dir/$file"
  nf=$(/usr/bin/expr $nf + 1)
```

done

With bash, you can use arithmetic expansion $((...)).

And of course this idea can be improved by using xargs - should not take longer than ~ 45 sec for 2.5 million files.

```
nd=0
ls | xargs -L 1000 echo | \
while read cmd;
do
  nd=$((nd+1))
  dir=$(printf "dir_%04d" $nd)
  mkdir $dir
  mv $cmd $dir
done
```

Comment: Please double-quote your variable references to protect them from unintended word splitting and globbing.
For robustness, your `read` commands should be prefixed with `IFS=` and use `-r`: `IFS= read -r ...`.
While rare, there could be filenames with leading or trailing whitespace or embedded ` \ ` chars.

Comment: Your first 2 commands process each file individually, which is what the OP himself tried, unsuccessfully.
2.5 million invocations of multiple external utilities take a long time.

Comment: Your `xargs` solution is not robust: it breaks with filenames with embedded spaces.

Answer (score -2):

I would use the following from the command line:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f |split -l 1000
for i in `ls x*`
do 
   mkdir dir$i
   mv `cat $i` dir$i& 2>/dev/null
done
```

Key is the "&" which threads out each mv statement.

Thanks to karakfa for the split idea.

Comment: While you may get away with using `for` in the `ls x*` case, because the filenames happen to have no embedded spaces or globbing metachars., it's  a [bad idea in general](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor); additionally, `\`cat $i`\` makes the resulting words subject to word splitting, which you're relying on on the one hand, but which causes failure with filenames with embedded spaces. Also, the resulting command line could end up being too long with this technique. Given that you already have a _file_ `$i`, you can't create a _directory_ of the same name.